# What’s the best way to learn “the articles”?

Tags: grammatical-mood

Die, der, das

Is there an easy method to their correct usage?

Comment: der-die-das are articles. 'dass' is a subjunction starting a certain type of subjunctive clause.

Comment: You could maybe elaborate a bit where exactly you have problems learning them? Apart from having gender-specific forms in German, there's not much difference to English.

Comment: There are some word endings like -chen (das) or -tion (die) that require a specific article. But in general you have to memorize the article for each word
.

Comment: Do you mean the gender of nouns? The key is practice. Drill each noun with its definite singular nominative article and its plural. As the latter is irregular as well. And for masculine nouns you also have to drill the genitive singular as it gives away whether that noun belongs to the strong or the weak declination. As soon you know a hundred nouns you will notice guessing the correct gender from the ending gets easier, and after five hundred nouns drilled that way you will see that you get it right most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Lange Rede, kurzer Sinn: lern mit dem Substantiv.